# Periodic workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have the following requirements and I also have some ways to do it

1. When a new item is added to the calendar a new FOLDER should be created.
2. Link the event to the new folder created

I can do it like:
1. Create an item adding event that creates the folder.
2. Create workflow  that creates a folder? Is this possible in SP Designer? In VS workflows I know its possible of course.

Thats the difficult part.
How can I make that after 30 days the folder has been created, then it moves automatically to another location?  A site workflow maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a timer job and schedule its execution for any period you want: http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/

Comment: they want it to be in sharepoint designer? can I make workflow for this?